# Visual Studio : NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, object

I am gotting a error and i don't know how to resolve:

**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

Here is the code :

```
private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string DataGridResources = "";

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in SettingsDGV.Rows)
        {
            DataGridResources = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            DataGridResources += '«';
            DataGridResources += row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            DataGridResources += '«';
            DataGridResources += row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            DataGridResources += '«';
        }

        MessageBox.Show(DataGridResources);
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

[Image of te error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFal7.png)

Comment: That's *very* strange-looking C code! Please clarify which language it is and/or correct your tags. At a guess, I would think it's C#.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and we do not know at which location the exception occurs. Use the debugger to check where the error occurs and to see variables and the call stack.

Comment: the error is on the last parentheses ' } '.

Comment: Maybe one or more of the values is null. Better check on that before using them..

Comment: Thanks @Taw... but i don't know why this error occor. But I got it fixed. I used a code : Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value); And the error doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: [Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToString_System_Object_System_IFormatProvider_) returns: _..the string representation of value, or Empty if value is an object whose value is null. If value is null, the method returns null._